# What does “vindication” mean in the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

Does "vindication" mean "the fact of proving that what US policymakers said or did was right after other people thought they were wrong:"?

> Celebrants atop the falling Berlin Wall on November 9, 1989.  Gorbachev saw Soviet communism's collapse as a new beginning, but many **U.S. policymakers hailed it as the ultimate vindication.**

> Source: The Untold History of the United States p.471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Celebrants atop the falling Berlin Wall on November 9, 1989. Gorbachev saw Soviet communism's collapse as a new beginning, but many U.S. policymakers hailed it as the ultimate vindication.

Your general interpretation is fine.

'Vindication' is defined similarly in the dictionary.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vindication

The quoted passage does not give details on whether *vindication* refers to *what had been said or done* or *U.S. policymakers*.  If we follow your sentence construction,

> the fact of proving that what US policymakers said or did was right after other people thought they were wrong

then it refers to the former.

Other than giving a few suggestions,  I have changed the pronoun near the end of the sentence to singular to maintain consistency; the pronoun has antecedent *what US policymakers had said or done* rather than *US policymakers*.

> "the fact of proving that what US policymakers [had] said or done *was* right after other people [had] thought [it was] wrong"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you captured the meaning very well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119499)

Comment: What?  The question was, Does "vindication" mean X?  My answer was, Yes.  How is that not providing an answer?

Comment: The aim of the StackExchange network is to provide a body of curated questions and answers to provide a resource for other people. Compare your answer with the accepted one and you will see why I felt it was more of a commentary than a full answer. It had come up in the Low Quality Posts review queue which is where I reviewed it.